# MTCH1010 internal pull up resistor draw more current than Icc?

Tags: microchip, proximity-sensor

I'm designing a Ultra-low power clock and I want to use a touch sensor for indicate the time since I want to reduce the power draw from the LED display.

I found the [MTCH1010](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/TXFG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MTCH1010-Data-Sheet-DS40002314A.pdf) from microchip. Based on the datasheet at its lowest power draw, its only draws 12.7uA on average which is perfect for me. But when I went down to the I/O characteristic, I saw the pull up resistor with the value of typical 35kΩ. The datasheet doesn't have any others information about it so base on my calculation with the assumption of the resistor is on each CFGx pin and I use a 1kΩ resistor to pull all of them to ground, the input will draw around 270uA which is more than x20 the Icc. This also higher than the AVR I use for the clock which draw only 12uA at 32.768kHz. The supply voltage for this device is 3.3V.

Can anyone familiar with this IC confirm for me whether this is true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to appendix in your datasheet, CFGx arent pulled up or pulled down. Why is pull up mentioned then? Probably left in datasheet as some sort of default value and nobody noticed yet.

Comment: I think that is true. But it's still weird to have that value mentioned in the datasheet since this one come from the microchip website. I think I'm gonna test and see it for myself. Thanks for your answer